# .Net dictionary type in protobuff

Tags: protocol-buffers

Can you help me identify this type in protobuff. Error is missing ">"

```
class SomeRequest
{
   Dictionary<long,List<string>> values;
}   
message SomeRequest
{
   map<int64,repeated string> values = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't do that. The closest you can get is a map to something that *has* a repeated element, so:

```proto
message SomeRequest
{
   map<int64,Thing> values = 1;
}
message Thing {
  repeated string items = 1;
}
```

Or in c# terms:

```cs
class SomeRequest
{
   Dictionary<long,Thing> values;
}
class Thing
{
    List<string> items;
}
```